# Joint laws and marginal laws

Tags: probability, random-variables, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

> We have 10 marbles enumerated from 1 to 10, and two boxes $B_1,B_2$. Marbles are inserted randomly in boxes. Let $X$ be a random variable counting the number of marble in $B_1$ and $Y$ a random variable counting marbles with odd number in $B_1$. Determine joint law and marginal laws for $X,Y$ and say if they are independent.

I'm having a lot of troubles with this exercise, the only thing I'm able to do is intuitively say that $X,Y$ aren't independent, and because they aren't independent I was trying to find Joint law to calculate the two marginals. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is there something missing from the definition of $Y$? There are five marbles with an odd number label.  How are the marbles put in the box?  If the location of each marble is independently and equally probably in each box, and $Y$ is the number of odd number labelled marbles in $B_1$, then it might be worth considering $Z$ as the number of even number labelled marbles in $B_1$  with $X=Y+Z$

Comment: @Henry I've edited, it was missing the fact that $Y$ was counting odd numbers in $B_1$

Comment: @Henry This way I think exist a characterization for joint distribution of a random variable defined as the sum of other two, am I right?

Comment: There are six possible values of $Y$ and six possible values of $Z=X-Y$, and it is not difficult to find the joint distribution of $Y$ and $Z$ and then turn that into a joint distribution for $Y$ and $X=Y+Z$ (which has eleven possible values), and then find the marginal distributions.  Your are correct that $Y$ and $X$ are not independent